# Нумерация одинаковых элементов списка, Python

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть два списка,

```
ll = ["10", "10", "10",  "11", "12"]
objList = ["Object_1", "Object_2", "Object_3", "Object_4", "Object_5"]
```

необходимо пронумеровать по порядку одинаковые элементы списка, то есть должен получиться словарь типо такого:

```
{"Object_1" : 10_1, "Object_2" : 10_2, "Object_3" : 10_3, "Object_4" : 11_1, "Object_5" : 12_1}
```

Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом, но получается чушь какая-то

```
ll = ["10", "10", "10",  "11", "12"]
objList = ["Object_1", "Object_2", "Object_3", "Object_4", "Object_5"]
i = 1
dd = dict()

for o in objList:
    for l in ll:
        dd[o] = l + "__" + str(i)
        i+=1
print dd
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

{x[1]:f'{c}_{i}'
 for c,g in groupby(zip(ll, objList), key=lambda x: x[0]) 
 for i,x in enumerate(g, 1)}
```

результат:

```
{'Object_1': '10_1',
 'Object_2': '10_2',
 'Object_3': '10_3',
 'Object_4': '11_1',
 'Object_5': '12_1'}
```

PS [форматирование в стиле F-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) работает для Python 3.6+

Comment: enumerate вторым параметром принимает начальное значение счетчика. Возможно это красивее, чем прибавлять при форматировании.

Comment: @Lecron, спасибо, так действительно лучше выглядит!